# XML data type in EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, ef4-code-only, xml-column

I would like to use SQL Server **xml** type as a column type for an entity class.

According to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d6b75ee-a1b7-44bf-b5f3-d32b12f2db66/xml-column-with-code-first?forum=adodotnetentityframework) it's possible to map such a column to **string** type:

```
public class XmlEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column(TypeName="xml")]
   public string XmlValue { get; set; }
}
```

The table is correctly generated in the datebase by this definition. New **XmlEntity** objects are also can be created.

But then I try to get some entity from the database:

```
var entity = db.XmlEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

An error occurs:

> **One or more validation errors were detected during model generation**
>   *System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType*: EntityType '*XElement*' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was with my wrapper property:

```
[NotMapped]
public XElement XmlValueWrapper
{
    get { return XElement.Parse(XmlValue); }
    set { XmlValue = value.ToString(); }
}
```

I didn't specified **NotMapped** attribute.

Comment: @alexey , great question and answer, but wouldn't the question make more sense if you included the XElement property in it -- per the MSDN articles? Currently there is no XElement property. So it's unclear that the only change is [NotMapped] attribute.

Answer (score 8):

Just to be complete. Here's all code needed, in one part.

```
[Column(TypeName = "xml")]
public String XmlContent { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public XElement InitializedXmlContent
{
    get { return XElement.Parse(XmlContent); }
    set { XmlContent = value.ToString(); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This's how you do that in Data Annotations, if you want to use Fluent API (and use a mapping class) then:

```
public partial class XmlEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<XmlEntity>
{
    public FilterMap()
    {
        // ...
        this.Property(c => c.XmlContent).HasColumnType("xml");

        this.Ignore(c => c.XmlValueWrapper);
    }
}
```

If you use Fluent API by overriding OnModelCreating on DbContext then just change those "this" with modelBuilder.Entity<XmlEntity>()