# MVC4 Code First - What data annotation gives me a data type of XML in the SQL database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have this property on one of my models:

```
[Required]
[AllowHtml]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

In my SQL database this gives me a data type of `nvarchar(MAX)`.

I want it to have a data type of `xml`.

What data annotation do I need to use?

I'm recreating some code from an old code first application and all I have is the database so it seems this is possible but I can't find any information on how.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190669/xml-data-type-in-ef-4-1-code-first and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631290/xml-columns-in-a-code-first-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
[Required]
[AllowHtml]
[Column(TypeName = "xml")]
public string Content { get; set; }
```